# Runtime error 91 in VBA excel for ADODB.Recordset

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm getting the runtime error 91 after I try a to send a sql statement in my excel application. Here's the following code:

```
'Module Consts:
Public rst1 As New ADODB.Recordset 'defined in a constants module
'Module Conn:
Public Sub GetDynSQLQuery(ByVal strQuery$, ByVal rs As ADODB.Recordset)   
    Set rs = Nothing
    If cn = "" Then Call ConnectToDb 'Sub set the variable "cn" with connectionstring to db and open the connection

    With rs
      .Source = strQuery       'Here comes the error
      .ActiveConnection = cn
      .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
      .LockType = adLockReadOnly
      .Open
    End With
End Sub

'Form1:
strSql = "SELECT * FROM tbl1"
Call GetDynSQLQuery(strSql, rst1)
```

Error Message:

> Object variable or With-block variable not set

What I'm doing wrong I cannot see it.

Comment: `Set rs = Nothing``and then use `rs`. So except if `rs` is a Public-like variable and is filled in `ConnectToDb`, it remains empty before being used, ergo the error!

Comment: @R3uK rs is set to `Nothing` or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: My bad for the previous formatting, see answer for easier explaining!

Comment: First, you need to stick `Option Explicit` at the top. Then, your connection should be opened, and then the procedure should probably be a `Function` that *returns* a recordset.... although I'd seriously reconsider the spaghetti going on here. Make the connection as short-lived as possible, and favor parameters and return values over globals. And drop that `Call` keyword from 1994, and `ByVal sql As String` would be clearer than `strQuery$` - see [Type Hints](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables/2960/type-hints#t=201702141509106963401) on Docs.SO.

Comment: Also [run-time error 91](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/8917/vba-run-time-errors/27750/run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set#t=201702141512534671052) on Docs.SO.

Comment: You set rs = nothing, instead you should set rs= New Adodb.Recordset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you do in the sub is that you empty the Argument (with `Set rs = Nothing`) that you just passed and then you use `rs` again.

So **except if `rs` is a *Public-like variable* and it's filled in `ConnectToDb`**,
it **remains empty before being used, ergo the error!**

First, try to remove `Set rs = Nothing` and if it's not enough, you'll need to look into `ConnectToDb`!

Secondly, you modify the Recordset inside the sub, but you try it to use it outside.
And the problem here was the use of `ByVal`, which pass a copy of the reference of the Object and so you canNOT modify the initial object, ergo the fact that the RecordSet is empty outside of the Sub! ;)

---

And as OP tested `rst1.RecordCount > 0` which was false (`rst1.RecordCount` was equal to -1),
He fixed it by setting `.CursorType` to `adOpenKeySet` instead of `adOpenForwardOnly`

---

```
Public Sub GetDynSQLQuery(ByVal strQuery$, rs As ADODB.Recordset)   
    'Sub set the variable "cn" with connectionstring to db and open the connection
    If cn = vbNullString Then Call ConnectToDb

    With rs
      .Source = strQuery       'No more error!^^
      .ActiveConnection = cn
      .CursorType = adOpenKeySet
      .LockType = adLockReadOnly
      .Open
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry but for me it doesn't work. I get no response data.

Comment: @yuro : How do use `GetDynSQLQuery`?

Comment: I use the `GetDynSQLQuery` only to send a sql statement how you can see above.

Comment: @yuro : Do you have an error still? Is `cn` a Public/Module variable?

Comment: Yes, it is. cn is defined as => `Public cn as New ADODB.Connection` in a public module `Consts`.

Comment: @yuro :  Do you still have an error? Is `cn` filled in `ConnectToDb`? What is the value of `strQuery` when it's filling `.Source`?

Comment: `cn` is filled with the connectionstring and `strQuery` contains the SELECT statement what I wrote above.

Comment: @yuro : The problem here was the use of `ByVal`, which pass a copy of the reference of the Object and so you canNOT modify the initial object, ergo the fact that the RecordSet is empty outside of the Sub! ;) See my edited answer and http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/7363/passing-arguments-byref-or-byval/24427/passing-objects-byref-and-byval#t=201702140904481730916

Comment: @yuro : Do you have an error? If so, which one and on which line? If not, what is the issue? Please edit your question and include a bit more of your code or at least a screenshot of a spy on `rs` at the end of the sub (place a breakpoint on the `End With`).

Comment: I found the problem. It was `adOpenForwardOnly`. Because I check in my If statement with `rst1.RecordCount > 0` and I always got the value `-1` .. `ByVal` was not the problem. I tested the sub with `ByVal` and it works too.

Comment: The `Set rs = nothing` I have deleted :). Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: @yuro : Glad you find where the issue was coming from! But indeed a bigger portion of your code would have make this easier! ;) As the only thing from the code you posted that was really wrong was the 1st thing I suggested! ;) Please accept to close

Comment: add on cursortype `adOpenKeySet`then I can remark your answer as finished :)